# Touched lines but not connected in ArcGIS 10.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing

Ι convert a contour file DWG to SHP file. The lines are touched but disconnected and they are broken in many places. Is there an automated way with a particular tolerance to automatically connect the touched vertex and merge the lines?

Comment: If you kept your DWG as lines, does “Extend Line (editing)” will not be any helpful to solve your problem?

Comment: No, I need to merge the line without select one by one the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Snap' geoprocessing tool, where you can select multiple lines and set a buffer. I don't have much experience using it, so unsure of any best practices or limitations off the top of my head.

Comment: You mean this tool
http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html

Comment: Yes--it's been a while since I used it, but did use to connect a network of lines imported from a CAD file once. There was some manual cleanup, where some lines were near multiple nodes, but that was much less time consuming than manually snapping.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: No, something is going wrong. First of all It doesn't recognize the units in Distance (it is Defined the coordinate system).

Comment: Could you post your error and example of the data that is being input?